# Firebase callable function call from web app

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

I have initialized a firebase app in my web page and defined a callable function as follows :

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "...xyz...",
    authDomain: "[project-id].firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://[project-id].firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "[project-id].appspot.com"
};
const app = firebase.initializeApp(config);
const mySimpleCallableFunction = firebase.functions(app).httpsCallable('mySimpleCallableFunction');
```

When the user clicks on a button, i call the function:

```
mySimpleCallableFunction({ param1: '...xyz...' })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
    });
```

I am getting a CORS error when trying to execute the function. I don't think CORS is the real issue here though as it looks to me like the URL for the callable function is NOT put together correctly, it has undefined where the project-id should be.

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://us-central1-undefined.cloudfunctions.net/mySimpleCallableFunction'
> from origin ...

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You are correct in your assessment that because the "access to fetch" error includes `undefined`, it sounds like you have a configuration problem. It looks like you may be missing `projectId` in your `config` object.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for this Sam. I concur :) How do i set it? I couldn't find anything in the API documentation and nothing on the web.

Comment: The [Firebase Configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/learn-more#config-object) documentation walks you through how to obtain the complete configuration object.